# How to hide a static UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How do you hide a static cell?

I would like to hide and static cell if an image does not exist.

I tried:

```
imageCell.hidden = YES; //did not work
```

I have seen answers suggesting to change datasource or use:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 0;// will hide all cell
}
```

But I couldnt find a way to do this with a specific view cell.

what I want to achieve:

```
if(image==nil){
//hide imageCell 
}
```

---

Now here is the catch , the image is downloaded asynchronously, so deleguate methods might be called before the attempted downlaod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 2 && !myImageIsLoaded)
        return 0; // Will hide just the third row of your table if myImageIsLoaded is false
    return 44;
}
```

And you can use the following to animate all whenever you want (e.g. each time an image as loaded) :

```
[myTable beginUpdate];
[myTable endUpdate];
```

If your cells are static so it should work. Otherwise you could encounter some problems.

Comment: this crashes the app EXC_BAD_ACCESS I will add more details

Comment: Can you provide your table datasource methods ?

Comment: I didnt implement any method, I just create outlets to datasource and deleguate since it just static cells

Comment: This is really close, I just dont want to return 44 for each row as I increase some of the cell size using the storyboard pplease advice

Comment: I accepted your post since it answers my question however I now have the height issue, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862380/how-to-return-custom-cell-height-from-storyboard

Answer (score 0):

If you want literally hide the cell that image does not exist, you can try this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return [cell imageView] ? 44.0f : 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: this crashes the app EXC_BAD_ACCESS