# How to return custom cell height from storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Earlier I asked a question on [how to hide a static cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859535/how-to-hide-a-static-uitableviewcell).

The [Best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21859747/3205189) I got hides the cell as I wanted but then it sets other cell height to `44`.

I would like to find a way to return the height provided by the story board since different cell could have different height.

also my table view is grouped, static , and many sections if that helps make it clearer.

I tried this

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 5 && image==nil && [indexPath section] == 1){
        NSLog(@"hide cvell");
        return 0;
    }
    return tableView.rowHeight;
}
```

it seems like `return tableView.rowHeight;` would return 44 also , so no changes :(

---

to make it short, here is what I need help with;

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 5 && image==nil && [indexPath section] == 1){
        NSLog(@"hide cvell");
        return 0;
    }
    return WhatEverSizeFromStoryboard;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a static cell, you should be able to get that using the super class' implementation:

```
return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```